# Optional routing params passed to controller

Tags: routes, laravel-routing, laravel-6, php-7.3

In Laravel 6.x, how do I get optional parameters to my controller? For example, my route:

```php
Route::get('/videos/{limit?}/{channel?}, VideosController@index);
```

And in my VideosController I have a method:

```php
public function index($limit=20, $channel=null)
{
   if (!is_null($channel))
   { 
      $channel_id = channel::where('name', $channel);
      $result = 
          <some complicated DB query>
          ->where('channel_id', $channel_id)
          ->limit($limit)
          ->first();
   } else {
      $result = 
          <some complicated DB query>
          ->limit($limit)
   }
}
```

But for some reason I never seem to fall into the `!is_null($channel)` case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `limit` and `channel` are both optional url segments in your route, your application will not know that you intend to populate the `channel` variable if the `limit` is missing. It will mistake it for being the `limit`.

What would be best in your case is to pass these as `GET` parameters, checking in your controller whether they have been populated.

Firstly, change your route to exclude the optional parameters:

```
Route::get('/videos', VideosController@index);
```

Then in your controller:

```
public function index()
{
   if (request()->has('channel'))
   { 
      $channel_id = channel::where('name', request('channel'));
      $result = 
          <some complicated DB query>
          ->where('channel_id', $channel_id)
          ->limit(request('limit', 20))
          ->first();
   } else {
      $result = 
          <some complicated DB query>
          ->limit(request('limit', 20))
   }
}
```

Then, the query for example would be `/videos?channel=example&limit=30`.

The `request()` helper allows a default value to be set if the parameter has been passed. Commonly you will see the request passed within the controller, so you can acheive the same thing with `$request->query('limit', 20)`.

I hope this helps.